# How to change the duration of CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am using CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder as default page transition, like this:

```
theme: ThemeData(
  pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
    TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
    TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
  }),
)
```

I like the transition, but it is a bit too fast. I want to slow it down, in other words i want to change the transition duration. How can i achieve this without building my own custom transition from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it:

```
class MyRoute extends MaterialPageRoute {
  MyRoute({builder}) : super(builder: builder);

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(/*desired duration here*/);
}
```

And then, instead of using

`Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyScreen()));`

I used

`Navigator.push(context, MyRoute(builder: (context) => MyScreen()));`